# What is the sum of the 12th to 20th terms (inclusive) of the arithmetic sequence 7,12,17,22,...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The solution to this question told that you should do S(20) - S(12). But I did S(20) - S(11). Here's my reasoning:

We are asked to find the sum of the 12th to 20th terms (inclusive), which I think means U12 + U13 + ... + U20.

S(20) = U1 + ... + U11 + U12 + U13 + U14  + U15  + U16 + U17  + U18  + U19  + U20

S(11) = U1 + ... + U11

Thus, to get U12 + ... + U20, you do S(20) - S(11).

I'm not sure why the answer says S(20) - S(12). Am I not interpreting the word "inclusive" properly?

Comment: Your reasoning sounds correct to me. I would interpret "inclusive" to mean that the 12th term and the 20th term should both be included in the sum.

Comment: Maybe the inclusive was only meant for $20$th term otherwise they are probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have the famous formula
$$\sum_{1}^{n} = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$

The sum from the question is actually
$$2n+5\sum_{1}^{n} = 2n+5\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$

From the $12^{th}$ to the $20^{th}$

$$2\cdot 20+5\dfrac{20(20+1)}2 - 2\cdot 11+5\dfrac{11(11+1)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Without computing each of these sums , you have a direct formula for that: there are $9$ terms in this sum, so, denoting $u_n$ the $n$-th term, the sum is
$$ S=9\,\frac{u_{12}+u_{20}}2.$$